# Count number of users from a certain country

Tags: sql, count

I have a table of users, and in this table I have a country field telling where these people are from (i.e. "Sweden", "Italy", ...). How can I do a SQL query to get something like:

```
Country     Number
Sweden      10
Italy       50
...         ...
```

Users select their countries from a list I give to them, but the list is really huge so it would be great to have a SQL query that can avoid using that list, that is look in the DB and give back only those countries which are in the database, because for example I have nobody from Barbados, even if I have that option in the country select field of the signup form :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give what you want. But you might want to cache the result of the query. With a lot of users it's quite a heavy query.

```
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    country
```

Perhaps a better idea is (assuming you don't need the counts) to do it like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT country
FROM
    users
```

Answer (score 6):

If the name of the country is in the Users table, try something like this:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT (*) AS Number
FROM Users
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY Country
```

If the name of the country is in the country table, then you will have to join

```
SELECT Contries.CountryName, Count (*) AS Number
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Countries
    ON Users.CountryId = Countries.CountryId
GROUP BY Countries.CountryName
ORDER BY Countries.CountryName
```

Comment: +1 Or a left join to countries, if there are users with no valid country ID.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this...?

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS Number
FROM Users
GROUP BY Country
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT
    Country, COUNT(*) AS 'Number'
FROM
     YourTable
GROUP BY
    Country
ORDER BY
    Country
```

You just group your data by country and count the entries for each country.

Or if you want them sorted by the number of visitors, use a different ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT
    Country, COUNT(*) AS 'Number'
FROM
     YourTable
GROUP BY
    Country
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count per country:

```
select country, count(*) from users group by country;
```

If you just want the possible values:

```
select distinct country from users;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  BillingCountry, COUNT(*)as Invoices
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY BillingCountry
ORDER BY Invoices DESC

Comment: Please consider adding some comments (not only the code) and also please consider formatting the code as code (using markdown syntax)